# Notation for a defining a grid of points

Tags: notation

I evaluated a function over a grid of points in three-dimensions. I would like to know what the standard notation is to define my grid of points?

In matlab notation the grid is defined by:

`[x,y,z] = ndgrid(logspace(-8,8,31),logspace(-8,12,41),linspace(0,pi/4,25));`

That is, `x` is spaced logarithmically (base 10) from $10^{-8}$ to $10^{8}$ using 31 points, `y` is spaced logarithmically from $10^{-8}$ to $10^{12}$ using 41 points, and `z` is spaced linearlly between $0$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}$ using 25 points.

What is the standard notation to define this grid of points?

Essentially, I'm trying to finish this sentence: "...we evaluated Eq. \ref{blah} over a grid of points in the parameter space defined by:..."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `ndgrid` corresponds, mathematically, to a [**Cartesian product**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of its input vectors. So your sentence could be something like

"We evaluated Eq. ?? over a grid of points in the parameter space $[-8,8] \times [-8,12] \times [0,\pi/4]$."

If you need to indicate the resolution of the grid, you can use a Cartesian product of *discrete sets* (instead of intervals). For example:

"We evaluated Eq. ?? over a grid of points in the parameter space $S \times T \times U$, where $S = \{-8,-7.5,-7, ..., ,8\}$, $T = \{-8, -7, -6, ..., 12\}$ and $U = \{0,\pi/40, 2\pi/40,... \pi/4\}$."

Comment: Thanks, that notation is pretty clean. However, it doesn't indicate the resolution of the grid. How would I enrich that notation to include the resolution?

Comment: @okj In that case you would need the Cartesian product of _discrete sets_, not of intervals. Pleas see updated answer